# Is Spring webflow a good portlet technology choice?

Tags: java, portlet, spring-webflow

I am working on a porlet app and it looks like the "main" portlet will be pretty complex, with some wizard-type functionality in it.  I started with plain Spring MVC but it's clear that the backing controller will become very big and unwieldy over time (to my eye).  I like to keep my classes small and static through the lifetime of an app.

I was considering the use of Spring Web flow, but a lot of the documentation on it seems to be from 08-timeframe - my question is, is this still a good technology choice for a modular portlet architecture?  Is there a way to redirect to standard MVC in certain use-cases within the same portlet/mode..?  I.e. to use SWF where it makes sense, but use MVC for other use-cases..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC supports portlets and so does webflow . We had an AbstractWizardFormController earlier in Spring for process ing data in a Step-By-Step approach which was replaces by Web flow . These store a Flow Id in every screen which decides the movement of the flow . Consider webflow if you have the following scenarios

```
There is a clear start and an end point.
The user must go through a set of screens in a specific order.
The changes are not finalized until the last step.
Once complete it shouldn't be possible to repeat a transaction accidentally.
```

As per the documentation [here](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow#documentation) . It does support portlets. The portlet intergration reference is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch14.html) . Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch11.html) for spring mvc integration .

Comment: Thanks Aravind,  I am trying out webflow now, it's integrated to the portlet and I'll see how I get on.  I guess I am really wondering if it's still the best solution for those kinds of problems or have things changed recently.  I have lots of questions - e.g. how to read request params, switch between flows, etc but I'll add those as separate ones.  Will leave the question open for now in case anyone else has positive or negative comments.  My case matches the above for about 50% of the features in the portlet, but other views may be more static in nature.